# How to send Node js output to HTML field value

Tags: node.js

I have an output from the node.js I need to assign the value to the HTML field . Can you help me on this ?

Comment: Can you show us, what you tried so far?

Comment: please add code sample, frameworks you are using

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You using nodejs, you need use EJS Template or Jade,you see:[Node.js ejs, jade module basic](https://medium.com/@booski/node-js-ejs-jade-module-basic-f98a4075d2bc)

Comment: I am getting refere from the var refere = req.headers['referer'];    and need to assign it to field in html   using node js